# JButton not showing up in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

Hello fellow programmers!

Are JButtons supposed to be able to show up in JFrame? I used the setVisible method on JButton but it would not appear.

Error Message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container
    at java.awt.Container.checkNotAWindow(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.addImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
    at FrameTest.initializeGameFrame(FrameTest.java:27)
    at FrameTest.main(FrameTest.java:17)
```

Code:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class FrameTest extends JFrame{

    private static final int gameWindowHeight = 700;
    private static final int gameWindowLength = 700;

    /** Set up frame for game window
     * 
     */

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FrameTest.initializeGameFrame();

    }

    public static void initializeGameFrame()
    {
        FrameTest gameFrame = new FrameTest();
        gameFrame.setSize(gameWindowLength, gameWindowHeight);
        gameFrame.setTitle("Frame Test- by Me");
        JButton gameButton =  new JButton("Start Game");
        gameButton.add(gameFrame);
        gameButton.setLocation(250, 250);
        gameButton.setVisible(true);
        gameFrame.setVisible(true);

    }


}
```

Comment: If you read the exception you get it provides a little insight to your problem: "adding a window to a container". IE, you're adding your `JFrame` to your `JButton` instead of the other way around.

Comment: Next time actually try to figure out the problem before asking.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add the button to the frame, try `gameFrame.add(gameButton);`

Answer (score 4):

you need to add button to frame.
such as `gameFrame.add(gameButton);`

Answer (score 4):

Add it to the panel otherwise it won't show up, ever.
     gameFrame.add(gameButton);

Answer (score 0):

you must have to add button to frame or panel : for example `JFrame.add(gameButton);`